# Pancakeswap Transaction failed message python

Tags: python, ethereum, swap, web3py

I am using this code piece with relevant changes
https://github.com/CodeWithJoe2020/pancakeswapBot/blob/main/cakebot.py
it worked with its contract. But when I try with the contract which has tax like %7 i get transaction failed error from pancakeswap.

```
pancakeswap2_txn = contract.functions.swapExactETHForTokens(
0,  # set to 0, or specify minimum amount of tokeny you want to receive - consider decimals!!!
[spend, tokenToBuy],
sender_address,
(int(time.time()) + 30000)
).buildTransaction({
'from': sender_address,
'value': web3.toWei(0.01, 'ether'),  # This is the Token(BNB) amount you want to Swap from
'gas': 159413,
'gasPrice': web3.toWei(speed, 'gwei'),
'nonce': nonce,
})
```

As you can see I am putting minimum 0 so in theory slippage should not matter.

Any ideas?

Comment: A little new to this as well but maybe I can help. Could you send a bscscan transaction link of the failed transaction so we can troubleshoot?

Comment: @Bobola reason seems to be less gas. I need to increase it to higher rate.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was fixed when I entered high gas value